# How cache works for Browser / Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

After an update of our website ( running on Apache ) we get some issues with .js files images ect ... It seems that old files were mixed up with new one. My question is how cache works ? Do we have to restart Apache each times we perform an update ? How Firefox know / handle new files from a website ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The caching mechanism is different for every browser.  If you would like more information regarding browser caching, I would suggest a post to Superuser.

For Apache, there is not native caching functionality within the server for static content.

Comment: How Apache knows about new files if we don't restart it? Same question for Firefox, how it knows that remote files changed?

Comment: Apache serves the files like any other file transfer mechanism, it isn't anything special in the case of the actual transfer of static content.  I suspect Firefox uses the `Last-Modified` header that Apache provides, which includes the timestamp for the last time the content changed.